# UIDatePickerView Text Cutting off when added as Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidatepicker

`UIDatePicker` Text gets Cut off while adding as subview in Pop up `viewController`.

Code is like below:

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, self.view.frame.size.height-120,  self.view.frame.size.width-20, 120)];

datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;

//  self.datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
datePicker.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

Check image:

[image: img1]

Edit:

```
Printing description of self->datePicker:
<UIDatePicker:0x7fd0b971c0a0; frame =(0 280; 300 120);layer =<CALayer: 0x7fd0bf30a2e0>>
(lldb) po self.view
<UIView: 0x7fd0bf331f40; frame = (0 0; 300 400); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = LM+RM+TM+BM; tag = 23942; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd0bbf81730>>
```

[image]

Comment: where are you writing this code? in didLoad ?

Comment: most probably you are getting wrong frame for datePicker.  `self.view.frame.size.width` is giving you extra width

Comment: Written this code in some method, which is called from some button click and i logged width which is correct as toolbar above has same width like datepicker@RahulMishra

Comment: one thing you can do is check the frame size of `self.view.frame` and `datePicker.frame` log these two values. I am sure these two have different widths.

Comment: are you adding this date picker to self.view or any other container view place between? because your code seems like you are add date picker in self.view and you screen shot seems like you are adding date picker in any container view which frame is less then date picker frame

Comment: i am presenting view controller and adding into it, so self.view.frame.size.width will be of same.

Comment: Check edited question

Comment: what is three down arrow of purple color ? is it part of app? if yes then your picker view's container's frame is less than self.view.frame

Comment: try to reduce picker view width(like 250) and then check that are you able to see the whole view

Answer (score 0):

Change your datepicker frame Width
Instead of self.view width you can set your popupviewsize.

> for example

instead of this

> > datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-120,  self.view.frame.size.width, 120)];

it should be

> > > > datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-120,  self.popupview.frame.size.width, 120)];

Comment: self.view is the popup viewcontroller view as i am adding it in popup view controller@Sherin

Comment: Your screenshot seems to be, you have someother containerview to dispaly that datepicker am i right?

Comment: The containerview of datepicker is less than the frame size of datepicker.